# Adding new data to one table and delete count from other table

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have 2 table ,  ( tableProducts , tableSpent)
I want to do " When I add new spent products at tableSpent , NumberofTotal = NumberofTotal - SpentProductnumber)

[image]

For example 3 products on Total Products

SEQDSD-PENCIL-15

QWEWQD-BOOK-10

ASGAGG-SHARPENER-45

I will add these infos at SpentProduct Table

ASGAGG - SHARPENER -20 - FOR SCHOOL

I want to delete this number ( 20 ) from TotalProducts 
so Total Products must look like

SEQDSD-PENCIL-15

QWEWQD-BOOK-10

ASGAGG-SHARPENER-25

This is my code for adding spent products at Spent table 
but Idk how can I delete this count number from total Products table 
When I clicked button1 , It must add 4 textboxes's data at SpentTable
and It must delete that number from TotalProducts name

How can I do that?

This is my code for adding.// Names  and number of rows are different cause of translation :)

```
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();

        string kayit = "insert into projeSarfBase(urunKodu,urunAdi,sarfAdet,projeKodu,projeAdi) values (@urunKodu,@urunAdi,@sarfAdet,@projeKodu,@projeAdi)";


        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(kayit, conn);

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunKodu", textBox1.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunAdi", textBox2.Text);

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sarfAdet", textBox3.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projeKodu", textBox4.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projeAdi", textBox5.Text);


        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: If total products is just a sum of spent products then it really shouldn't have it's own table, you should just dynamically calculate the data based on the spent table data as and when you need it.

Comment: no It shows how many products at product .  I mean total number for every product, Pencil,book,paper .... +50 producuts

Comment: The code include insertion using `SqlCommand` but you have tag of `dataGridView` so I am not sure where do you have difficulties to insert? to SQL table or to `dataGridView`?

Comment: Do you mean it shows how many of each product you have on stock (E.g. we have 45 sharpeners) and by 'spent' do you mean 'we used/gave away 20 of them?)

Comment: @JeffUK yes , For example : We spent 20 sharpeners for school , so We gave it , We have 25 now , 
I must see 25 on TotalProduct table

Answer (score 0):

The way that commercial products will handle this is as follows.

Create a 'Transactions' table. As follows

```
Create Table InventTransactions (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ProductID NVarChar(25),
Reference NVarchar(25),
TransactionDate datetime,
Quantity int)
```

When you want to record the purchase of products, you set the quantity to a positive value

```
insert into InventTransactions (ProductID,Reference,TransactionDate,Quantity)
Values ('SHARPENER','Purchase Order #1',getDate(),45);
```

And when you 'Spend' the products, you post a negative quantity

```
insert into InventTransactions (ProductID,Reference,TransactionDate,Quantity)
Values ('SHARPENER','ForSchool',getDate(),-20);
```

At any point, you simply add up all of the quantities to get your result

Total Products:

```
Select ProductID, sum(quantity) from InventTransactions group by ProductID
Having SUM(Quantity)>0
```

This approach improves performance (you only have to stamp one entry per transaction) and gives you a permanent record of where the inventory came from, and where it went.  It also allows you ask more interesting questions of the data like "What was the inventory at X date" or 'How much of this item do I use every week" (by filtering on date).